# yum install in fedora 20 [Google chrome]

Tags: fedora, yum

I installed fedora 20 64bit to my PC along with Win 10 in duel boot and then tried to install Chrome browser according to this article, but I get below error when executing the last command. `[sudo yum install google-chrome-stable]`

> Loaded plugins: langpacks, refresh-packagekit google | 3.0 kB 00:00
>   http://dl.google.com/linux/rpm/stable/i386/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno
>   -1] Error importing repomd.xml for google: Damaged repomd.xml file Trying other mirror. Error: failure: repodata/repomd.xml from google:
>   [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
>   http://dl.google.com/linux/rpm/stable/i386/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno
>   -1] Error importing repomd.xml for google: Damaged repomd.xml file

Then I tried the URL (in above error message) in my browser(firefox) and got following error

> Application Blocked! You have attempted to use an application which is
>   in violation of your internet usage policy.  Yum.Tool Category: Update
>   URL:http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/rpm/stable/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml
>   Client IP: 192.168.20.36 Server IP: 74.125.200.136 User name:

I tried that same url in windows (same pc & same network settings in duel boot) then it's working (can download a xml file)

What could be the problem here ?

EDIT -

I tried updating firefox and get the same error message as above.

Comment: Fedora 20 is ancient.Please consider installing a more recent version. Fedora 27 is the current version.

Comment: The problem is not with Fedora 20 definitely. Check the "internet usage policy" with your ISP

Comment: No I think the problem is within my OS

Answer (score 0):

The `Fedora 20` is not guilty. Although I had to install the nss from `Fedora 24`'s release as `google-chrome-current` requires NSS of version 3.28 or above, all other packages come from `Fedora 20`:

```
-bash-4.2# rpm -q fedora-release nss
fedora-release-20-4.noarch
nss-3.30.2-1.0.fc24.x86_64
-bash-4.2# yum install https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64.rpm
google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64.rpm                                                                                                                                                                                |  47 MB  00:00:04     
Examining /var/tmp/yum-root-BRyfCa/google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64.rpm: google-chrome-stable-63.0.3239.132-1.x86_64
Marking /var/tmp/yum-root-BRyfCa/google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64.rpm to be installed
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package google-chrome-stable.x86_64 0:63.0.3239.132-1 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

==============================================================================================================================================================================================================================================
 Package                                                   Arch                                        Version                                                Repository                                                                 Size
==============================================================================================================================================================================================================================================
Installing:
 google-chrome-stable                                      x86_64                                      63.0.3239.132-1                                        /google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64                                      177 M

Transaction Summary
==============================================================================================================================================================================================================================================
Install  1 Package

Total size: 177 M
Installed size: 177 M
Is this ok [y/d/N]: y
Downloading packages:
Running transaction check
Running transaction test
Transaction test succeeded
Running transaction (shutdown inhibited)
  Installing : google-chrome-stable-63.0.3239.132-1.x86_64                                                                                                                                                                                1/1 
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl start  atd.service
  Verifying  : google-chrome-stable-63.0.3239.132-1.x86_64                                                                                                                                                                                1/1 

Installed:
  google-chrome-stable.x86_64 0:63.0.3239.132-1                                                                                                                                                                                               

Complete!
-bash-4.2#
```

So, check the "internet usage policy" with your ISP

Comment: Still I get the same error after download completes